# How to apply CSS styles to HTML injected and styled by a Javascript script that's beyond my control

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

I've created a blog using Blogger.com.

You can edit some of the HTML, including the CSS styles that load inside the head.

To do various things on the blog, such as adding a search box, you enable various "gadgets" within Blogger's dashboard. These insert Javascript into your page that injects HTML.

You cannot edit the Javascript scripts. The scripts style the HTML that they inject using inline CSS.

How can I override these styles with the CSS that I insert into the head?

I've tried !important and being as specific as possible with my selectors.

Comment: Hi Steven, do you think you can post some of the relevant code, like the CSS you're using and maybe an example of the JavaScript that's getting in the way? Without seeing actual code, you're just asking theoretical questions, and StackOverflow is more for specific programming problems. Consider using the [edit] link to add those code examples. We're happy to help! Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the rules of [CSS Speicificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) inline styles pretty much always win. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RichardTowers/HmXXc/).

There are some limits as to what you'll be able to achieve from stylesheets, but if you have access to some javascript on the page then you should be able to style things however you like.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with adding !important to the CSS rule.

Or write some js yourself

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out the answer. You just insert the styles here:

```
</body>
  <style type='text/css'>
     /* insert styles here */
  </style>
</html>
```

Then the styles load after the Javascript injects the HTML, overwriting the inline styles.